# Apache redirect to shiny server return 404

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, shiny-server

I run shiny server on an Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu) instance with Apache 2.4 installed. I want to create user authentication so I set up shiny-server to listen to localhost only. 
The shiny server configuration looks like:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838 localhost;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

I added the following lines at the end of the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   Redirect /TestEC2 /TestEC2/
   ProxyPass /TestEC2/ http://localhost:3838/TestEC2/
   ProxyPassReverse /TestEC2/ http://localhost:3838/TestEC2/
   RedirectMatch permanent ^/TestEC2$ /TestEC2/

   <Location /TestEC2>
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Enter your login name and password"
       AuthUserFile /home/ubuntu/users
       Require valid-user
   </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Assessing the App directly via Port 3838 prior to adding `localhost` in the shiny-server configuration worked fine. Also restarting both Apache and the Shiny Server gave no Error/Warning. I can also see my default starting page when assessing Port 80. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

After looking around for some time I found the solution. The information that I put into `apache2.conf` needs to go into `sites-enables/000-default.conf`. Then restart apache2. Also make sure that the modules `proxy` , `proxy_http` and `proxy_connect` are loaded (e.g. `a2enmod proxy`)